# How to manage different screen resolution in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, screen-resolution

I want to know what is the best way to handle the different screen resolutin while developing apps in windows phone 7.

Because i develope all application in 480 x 800 pixels and as i know not all mobile support  480 x 800 pixel  resolution .

If I hardcode the width, height, margin, etc. in the xaml, than it will be create problem  when the phone does not support 480x800 resolution.

So what is the best way to manage all resolutin in single application? like in android have differnt folder for diffrent resolution(Hdpi,Ldpi).

Help me

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP8 Emulator screen size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470605/wp8-emulator-screen-size)

Comment: yes,wp7 does not support different solution but wp8 support this one and as per i know wp8 have very complex method for resolution.Suppose i have 100 image in diffrent page so  i have to use 300 "if" condition.this is much complex.Any other best solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for handling  diffrent screen resolution while developing application in wp8.

JustinAngel anser is also right but its some complecated because it contains a lot of code that needs to be maintained and its some what difficult.

So use Telerik RedControls.No code-behind is necessary to maintain and a simple straightforward way of loading different images depending on the resolution.

Please Reffer this link

[Multi-Resolution support in Windows Phone 8 Made Easy](http://blogs.telerik.com/michaelcrump/posts/12-12-17/multi-resolution-support-in-windows-phone-8-made-easy)

Hope this is help for all wp8 developer.

Answer (score 3):

Please read my previous answers on the topic: [Zen of WP8 Multi-resolution support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13470605/wp8-emulator-screen-size/13473129#13473129), [APIs for WP8 mutli-resolution](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Multi_resolution), [DevCenter multiple XAP support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431951/how-do-i-get-my-windows-phone-7-app-to-show-up-in-the-windows-phone-8-marketplac/13475744#13475744), and [WP7 & WP8 co-development guide](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html).

Specifically have a look at the [WP7 & WP8 co-development guide under Runtime adaption](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!co-development-and-porting-guide.html;#toc_Runtimeadaptation). That has this code snippet:

```
public Uri GetScaledImageUri(String imageName) 
{
    int scaleFactor = (int)Application.Current.Host.Content.ScaleFactor;
    switch (scaleFactor)
    {
        case 100: return new Uri(imageName + "_wvga.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        case 150: return new Uri(imageName + "_720p.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        case 160: return new Uri(imageName + "_wxga.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        default:  throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown resolution type");
    }
}

// Next line will load a correct image depending on the resolution of the device
MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(GetScaledImageUri("myImage"));
```

Also have a look at [APIs for WP8 mutli-resolution](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/What%27s_new_in_Windows_Phone_8#Multi_resolution) that has these three mutually exclusive code snippets:

```
Image myImage = new Image();
if (MultiRes.Is720p)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("puppies.720p.jpg"));
else if (MultiRes.IsWvga)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("puppies.wvga.jpg"));
else if (MultiRes.IsWxga)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("puppies.wxga.jpg"));

if (MultiRes.Is720p)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"assets\16by9AspectRatio\puppies.jpg"));
else
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"assets\15by9AspectRatio\puppies.jpg"));

if (MultiRes.IsHighResolution)
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"assets\HD\puppies.jpg"));
else
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"assets\SD\puppies.jpg"));
```

Comment: JustinAngel:thanks and you mean wp7 support only 480x800 pixel resolution?

Comment: yes that is fine but i want to diffrent resolution in same project so what about images folder and how to apply diffrent images and grid or stack panel size according diffrent resolution

Comment: You'll have to write code yourself to change images based on resolutions. You can make up your own file & folder name conventions. Again, See the code example for that under "Runtime adaption" in the linked article and specifically the method "GetScaledImageUri".

Comment: Yes, WP7 the platform only supports WVGA (480x800) so WP7 apps will only run in 480x800 logical pixels with 15:9 aspect ratio even on WP8. Once the app is recompiled to WP8 apps can support 16:9 aspect ratio. Please read the attached articles. However, WP7 apps running on WP8 WXGA/720P will have their images and videos bitmap scaled which might not look good.

Comment: :thanks but i think its very complecated when i have more than 10 image control than i have to apply 30 condition? and all images are apply on coding part? what is the work of xaml side?

Comment: :thanks sir you give right solution but its much complex.Resolution is not possible like iphone? for example in iphone contain only one image folder with diffrent name of image and system take image autometicaly as per phone resolution.

Comment: @JustinAnjel:Hello sir this is mansinh dodiya(.net and windows phone developer).may i take your facebook or twiter id?